# Does CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name always return the language code and country/region code separated by a hyphen?

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, currentculture

Does CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name always return the language code and country/region code separated by a hyphen? I have been told that CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name can sometimes return just the two letter language code, but I have found no documentation to substantiate this claim.

Comment: Here are some relevant links to help
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.name?view=net-6.0#remarks
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c

Comment: If it's a neutral Culture, then yes. What are you looking for?

Comment: I don't understand the down vote.  Regarding what is returned by CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name, the official Microsoft documentation DOES NOT mention what CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name returns if using a neutral culture value.  You have to look carefully at the example further down in the documentation to determine that only the two-character neutral culture value is returned if the CultureInfo object is created using a neutral culture string.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jimi for your reference to neutral culture. I found the following example that demonstrating a neutral culture, where only "fr" is specified, and therefore CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name will only return the two-character language code:

```
   public static void Main()
   {
      double value = 1634.92;
      CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-CA");
      Console.WriteLine("Current Culture: {0}",
                        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
      Console.WriteLine("{0:C2}\n", value);

      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr");
      Console.WriteLine("Current Culture: {0}",
                        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
      Console.WriteLine("{0:C2}", value);
   }


// The example displays the following output:
//       Current Culture: fr-CA
//       1 634,92 $
//
//       Current Culture: fr
//       1 634,92 €
```